# bandwidth in Amazon AW2 trying to calculate TCO

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to work out TCO for Amazon AWS for network what is 400GB upload and download per month comparable to Mbit/s in the network calculator?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot calculate raw network bandwidth (Mbits per second) of the data centre link from average download rate, or vice versa.

The download rate will depend all all sorts of other factors, including end-to-end network latency, raw bandwidth in the entire network path from client to server, network congestion, the ability of the end points to read / write the data from / to disk, etcetera.

Also, you need to decide if you want your download / uploads to happen quickly or slowly.  What "user experience" do you want your users to have?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the response, what Mbits would you recommend for users to have a good streaming experience?

Comment: I wouldn't make a recommendation.  It depends on what you are streaming; videos? audio? compressed?  Other stuff?  It also depends on their hardware / networking ... and their expectations.  And how many simultaneous streaming users you need to support.

Comment: What I suggest you do is to build a simple prototype / mockup that will allow you to figure out what Mbit/s you will need to sustain acceptable streaming for N simultaneous users with >>your<< workload. Use the results of that for your TCO estimates.  (But bear in mind that they can only ever be estimates.  And there are probably all sorts of "variables" in your TCO equations .... like the number of users, numbers of downloads, size of downloads, etc)